# Nginx does not detect an upstream server as down

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, opnsense

I have an upstream (generated by OpnSense Nginx plugin)

```
upstream upstream9dbd5491033b477e84564ebe3e516c0b {
        server aa.bb.cc.d1:443 weight=1 max_conns=10000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10;
        server aa.bb.cc.d2:443 weight=1 max_conns=10000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10;
        server aa.bb.cc.d3:443 weight=1 max_conns=10000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10;
}
```

and host `aa.bb.cc.d3` is down. But Nginx does not detect the host as down, unless I add the `down` flag to it.

I expect Nginx to not forward any requests to the server anymore. But unfortunately, it still does (there is a significant performance change when I "down" the server manually).

Also the statistics view in OpnSense says, that server `aa.bb.cc.d3` is `up`.

The documentation [1] is quite clear, except the following facts:

> What is considered an unsuccessful attempt is defined by the proxy_next_upstream, fastcgi_next_upstream, uwsgi_next_upstream, scgi_next_upstream, memcached_next_upstream, and grpc_next_upstream directives.

Well, I have no `proxy_next_upstream` [2] and the default value is `error`:

> an error occurred while establishing a connection with the server, passing a request to it, or reading the response header

But the default of `proxy_next_upstream_timeout` is `0`:

> Limits the time during which a request can be passed to the next server. The 0 value turns off this limitation.

Do these default values disable that feature completely, or what else could be the reason, that Nginx still keeps a server up, that is not reachable at all?

References:

[1] https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

[2] https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that the feature to "mark a host down automatically after n retries" is not a basic feature a may be available in the commercial healthcheck module: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_hc_module.html

The only chance to get this feature work, is to reduce `max_fails` and `fail_timeout` and let `proxy_next_upstream` do the job.